# Jquery multiple checkbox get value in var or print in span

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

the code for html is :

```
<div id="container"><h1>Add-ons</h1>
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="10" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 1 - 10 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="20" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 2 - 20 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="40" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 3 - 40 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="60" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 4 - 60 QR <br />
</div>

<div> I want more add-ons
<select id="more" name="more">
    <option value="0 QR">0</option>
    <option value="30 QR">1</option>
    <option value="50 QR">2</option>
    <option value="100 QR">3</option>
</select>
<span id="span"></span>
 User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>
```

Jquery:

```
//For select          

      function displayVals() {
      var singleValues = $("#more").val();         
      $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " + 
                  singleValues);
         }

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();
//For  checkboxes
var $cbs = $('input[name="ch1"]');
$cbs.click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $cbs.each(function() {
        if (this.checked)
            var singleValues = $("#more").val();
            total += +this.value + singleValues;
    });
    $("#usertotal").text(total);
});
```

I want at the user total usage:  to create the sum of the checkboxes and add with the value of the option so that if I select 1 checkbox and 2 plus option 1 I will have written in user total usage: 60 . 
Thank YOU in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/GNDAG/

Hope it helps. You can read more about `each` [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

However, like @nnnnnn mentioned, your html isn't right -- ID attributes need to be unique.

**Code**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
   var total_span = 0;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            total_span += parseInt($(this).prop('value'), 10);
        }
    });

    $("#usertotal").html(total_span);
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that it is invalid html to use the same id for multiple elements. Select the checkboxes using their name attribute. On click of any checkbox loop through them all, and add the value of any checked ones. Note that the values need to be converted to numbers, which I do with the unary plus operator.

```
var $cbs = $('input[name="ch1"]');

$cbs.click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $cbs.each(function() {
        if (this.checked)
            total += +this.value;
    });
    $("#usertotal").text(total);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6GX7g/

Comment: this is ok but it does not do the sum of the values . It just bind-s em' together. so if i check 1'st and 2'nd is will show up "User total usage: 1020 QR" instead of 30 QR

Comment: @nnnnnn I understand that adding `+` to `this.value` prevents concatenation of the values. But can you explain that or references of the explanation.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu - From my answer: "Note that the values need to be converted to numbers, which I do with the unary plus operator." Once converted to numbers, the values are added as numbers (not concatenated as strings). For more information have a look at [MDN's explanation of JS arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_(Unary_Plus)).

Comment: @nnnnnn +1 nice post. always using `parseInt`.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu - Thanks. I almost never use `parseInt` - it's good if you need to convert numbers that aren't base 10, or you want to round down a decimal value, and if you don't mind that it ignores non-numeric characters at the end of the string such that `parseInt("123xyz",10)` returns `123`, and of course you always need to include the radix in the second param or by default strings with leading zeros are taken as base 8 (by some but not all browsers). `Number("123")` is generally better, but the unary plus is my preference.

Comment: @nnnnnn IMHO, your preference is simple and better according to the `Mozilla Documentation` link.

Answer (score 0):

```
try it:


$('input:checkbox').change(function(){ 
var tot=0;
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
tot+=parseInt($(this).val());
});
$('#usertotal').html(tot)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

[WORKING DEMO jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TvEc/4/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container"><h1>Add-ons</h1>
<input type="checkbox" class="numbers" name="ch1" value="10" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 1 - 10 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" class="numbers" name="ch1" value="20" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 2 - 20 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" class="numbers" name="ch1" value="40" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 3 - 40 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" class="numbers" name="ch1" value="60" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 4 - 60 QR <br />
</div>
User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>
```

Jquery/javascript:

```
  var getCheckedBoxValues = function() {
   var values = []
   $(".numbers:checked").each(function() {
       values.push($(this).val());
   });
   return values;
   };
    $('.numbers').click(function () {
   $('#usertotal').html();        
   var usertotal = 0;                
   var values = getCheckedBoxValues();
    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        usertotal += parseInt(values[i]);
    }
    $('#usertotal').html(usertotal);
  });
```