# jQuery checkbox and select - sum the values and add in var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, checkbox

The explanation is below the code:

The code for HTML is :

```
<div id="container"><h1>Add-ons</h1>
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="10" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 1 - 10 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="20" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 2 - 20 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="40" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 3 - 40 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="60" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 4 - 60 QR <br />
</div>

<div> I want more add-ons
<select id="more" name="more">
    <option value="0 QR">0</option>
    <option value="30 QR">1</option>
    <option value="50 QR">2</option>
    <option value="100 QR">3</option>
</select>
<span id="span"></span>
 User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>
```

jQuery:

```
//For select          

function displayVals() {
  var singleValues = $("#more").val();         
  $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " + 
    singleValues);
}

$("select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();

//For  checkboxes
var $cbs = $('input[name="ch1"]');
$cbs.click(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $cbs.each(function() {
    if (this.checked)
      var singleValues = $("#more").val();
      total += +this.value + singleValues;
  });
  $("#usertotal").text(total);
});
```

I want the user total usage: to create the sum of the checkboxes and add the value of the option so that if I select checkbox 1 and 2 plus option 1 I will have written in user total usage: 60.

Comment: Don't forget to follow up on the advice we gave you [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12063243/615754): change your element id attributes to make them all unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jUUYJ/1/)** for your code.

Hope this is what you wanted.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"><h1>Add-ons</h1>
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="10" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 1 - 10 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="20" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 2 - 20 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="40" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 3 - 40 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="60" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 4 - 60 QR <br />
</div>

<div> I want more add-ons
<select id="more" name="more">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="30">1</option>
    <option value="50">2</option>
    <option value="100">3</option>
</select>
<span id="span"></span>
 User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>
```

Javascript:

```
function displayVals() {
      calcUsage();
      var singleValues = $("#more").val();         
      $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " + 
                  singleValues + ' QR');
}
var $cbs = $('input[name="ch1"]');
function calcUsage() {
    var total = $("#more").val();
    $cbs.each(function() {
        if (this.checked)
            total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(this.value);
    });
    $("#usertotal").text(total + ' QR');
}

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();
//For  checkboxes

$cbs.click(calcUsage);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is your answer

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H4d7W/)

```
  $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
var tot=0;
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
tot+=parseInt($(this).val());
});
 tot+=parseInt($('#more').val());
$('#usertotal').html(tot)
});

 $('#more').change(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').trigger('change');
 });
```

Comment: This worked best for me because not only do I have more than one checkbox, but I have more than one dropdown menu as well. this counted everything easily.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're simply missing a block for your `if` statement in the `each` function: you don't want to increment `total` unless `this.checked` is true. Furthermore, you want to convert *all* strings to numbers so that you don't get string concatenation from `+` - I've used `parseInt`. Also, from your description, it seems like you only want to add the value from the `option` *once*, not each time through the loop, so use that to initialize `total`:

```
$cbs.click(function()
{
    var total = parseInt($("#more").val());

    $cbs.each(function()
    {
        if (this.checked)
            total += parseInt(this.value);
    });

    $("#usertotal").text(total);
});
```

But you also want to do this calculation and update when the `select` changes, so you should pull this loop out into a separate function and call it using `click`:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var total = parseInt($("#more").val());

    $cbs.each(function()
    {
        if (this.checked)
            total += parseInt(this.value);
    });

    $("#usertotal").text(total);
}

$("#more").change(calculateTotal);
$cbs.click(calculateTotal);
```

Comment: From the OP's description, he or she doesn't really want to add `singleValues` on every loop iteration, it just needs to be added to the total once. (So you could initialise `var total = +$("#more").val();` and remove the `singleValues` variable altogether...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $('input[name="ch1"]').change(); // trigger change to recalculate
});
$('input[name="ch1"]').change(function() {
    var singleValues = 0;
    $('input[name="ch1"]:checked').each(function() { // loop through checked inputs
        singleValues = +this.value + singleValues;
    });
    singleValues += (+$('#more').val().replace('QR', '').trim());  // add drop down to checked inputs
    $("#usertotal").text(singleValues);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/5s8qr/

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEkjm/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container"><h1>Add-ons</h1>
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="10" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 1 - 10 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="20" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 2 - 20 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="40" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 3 - 40 QR <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="60" id="qr1" />Add-on Number 4 - 60 QR <br />
</div>

<div> I want more add-ons
<select id="more" name="more">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="30">1</option>
    <option value="50">2</option>
    <option value="100">3</option>
</select>
<span id="span"></span>
 User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>
```

Javascript:

```
function displayVals() {
      calcUsage();
      var singleValues = $("#more").val();         
      $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " + 
                  singleValues + ' QR');
}
var $cbs = $('input[name="ch1"]');
function calcUsage() {
    var total = $("#more").val();
    $cbs.each(function() {
        if (this.checked)
            total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(this.value);
    });
    $("#usertotal").text(total + ' QR');
}

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();
//For  checkboxes

$cbs.click(calcUsage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done complete bins for above query. here is demo link as well.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp85

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>
    Add-ons
  </h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="10" id="qr1" />
  Add-on Number 1 - 10 QR 
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="20" id="qr1" />
  Add-on Number 2 - 20 QR 
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="40" id="qr1" />
  Add-on Number 3 - 40 QR 
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="60" id="qr1" />
  Add-on Number 4 - 60 QR 
  <br />
</div>
<div>
  I want more add-ons
  <select id="more" name="more">
    <option value="0 QR">
      0
    </option>
    <option value="30 QR">
      1
    </option>
    <option value="50 QR">
      2
    </option>
    <option value="100 QR">
      3
    </option>
  </select>
  <span id="span">
  </span>
  User total usage: 
  <span id="usertotal">

  </span>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="ch1"]:checkbox').change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('input[name="ch1"]:checked').each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        total += parseInt($('#more').val());
        $('#usertotal').html(total);
    });
    $('#more').change(function() {
        var selectVal = $(this).val().trim();
        if (parseInt(selectVal) > 0) {
            $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " + selectVal);
        } else {
            $("#span").html("");
        }
        $('input[name="ch1"]:checkbox').trigger('change');
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp85