# sum values from inputs and selects in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i was looking for a script in jquery to sum values from inputs and select options and i found this script:

SOURCE: [jQuery checkbox and select - sum the values and add in var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066649/jquery-checkbox-and-select-sum-the-values-and-add-in-var)

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/H4d7W/

The only problem is that my form contains multiple inputs and multiple selects.

I was thinking something like this:

REPLACE:

```
tot+=parseInt($('#more').val());
$('#usertotal').html(tot)
});

     $('#more').change(function(){
      $('input:checkbox').trigger('change');
     });
```

FOR:

```
tot+=parseInt($('select > option:selected'').val());
$('#usertotal').html(tot)
});

     $('select > option:selected'').change(function(){
      $('input:checkbox').trigger('change');
     });
```

Any idea of how can i edit that code to accomplish this.

In the link below i created a Demo with the first select to sum between INPUTS.

**JSFIDDLE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/B9ufP/

Comment: That completely depends on the structure of your HTML. At the very least you should not have syntax errors in your code. Please post your HTML and create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. Also it's not clear to me if you have multiple select elements or a multi-select element.

Comment: OK @FelixKling i have created a DEMO here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/B9ufP/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have a `reduce` method (yet), but it does have `each` which you can use to the same effect.

```
var sum = 0;
$('select > option:selected').each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
```

Comment: yeah but how would it apply when it has to get multiple INPUTS and SELECTS http://jsfiddle.net/B9ufP/

Comment: You can pass multiple selectors to jQuery, comma separated.  ie `$('option:selected, input:checkbox:checked').each(...`

Answer (score 0):

this is what i was looking for thanks for your help:

```
var $total = $('#usertotal');
$('input,select').change(function () {
    var tot = 0;
    $('input:checkbox:checked, select > option:selected').each(function () {
        var per_op = $(this).attr('value');
        if (per_op) {       
        tot += Number(per_op);
        }
    });
    var final_result = tot.toFixed(2);
    $total.html(final_result)
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zFCvV/6/