# How to get sum of few radio button values in a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, radio-button

following foreach loop run inside another foreach loop

```
foreach(array_combine($hotels, $charges) as $hotel => $charge){       
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$location' value='$charge'> $hotel - <b>Rs.$charge.00</b><br>";
}
```

$charge is some integer value, I want to get the sum value of this radio button selections. How can I do this?

Comment: **want to get the sum value of this radio button** means ??

Comment: Post your array structure along with the expected result

Comment: i think you need jquery/js to do so when a user selects radio button as per location and sum the total charges

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you wanted only selected checkboxes sum or all. If all, then this will work.

Create new variable and add `$charge` to it on every iteration.

```
$chargeSum = 0;
foreach(array_combine($hotels, $charges) as $hotel => $charge){       
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$location' value='$charge'> $hotel - <b>Rs.$charge.00</b><br>";
    $chargeSum += $charge;
}
echo 'Sum: '.$chargeSum;
```

Otherwise you have to use jQuery, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066649/jquery-checkbox-and-select-sum-the-values-and-add-in-var) has couple of answers for this.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?